# sorting specific digit number from text and return a note if no number is present

Tags: python, csv

i have some text records which have numbers in it. i wanna extract only 5 digit numbers and leave everything else. some have multiple 5 digit number and i take only the 2nd one.
some of the records dont have any number or it's <5 digit. so whenever i try to use items[0] or items[1] it returns 'list index out of range'. i understand i need to make a loop which will return note like 'not a 5 digit num' but where and how. records are associated with other attributes so cannot exclude any record. also, i want the numbers (&note if no num or <5digit)in rows so that they match with attributes. i am very new to python and need help.
as far i was able to write this:

```
zipfile=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    reader=[]
    for row in zipfile:
        value=re.findall(r'(\d{5})', str(row))
        reader.append(value)

zipcode=[]
for items in reader:
    if len(items)> 1:
        zipcode.append(items[1])
    else:
        zipcode.append(items[0])

with open('C:\sample_Output.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    for val in zipcode:
                wr.writerow([val])
```

Sample input:

```
as 34567
ds 34 fd
12234 12323 asds
sdfjd 57645 fdsn 23412
```

Desired output:

```
34567
12323
23412
```

Comment: In the future, please [edit] your question to provide these details.  As you can see, these comments are not very good for communicating these things, and the question should stand on its own even if comments are deleted.  Also, please review the transcription and consider deleting the now-obsolete comments.

Comment: @tripleee Much better now. But it's still not clear what should happen if the line contains only single 5 digit number.

Comment: @khan Please provide all the cases.

Comment: @khan Since you are new here, I'll recommend taking a [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Input file: `fin`

```
as 34567 ds 34 fd 12234 12323 asds
as ds 34 fd 12234 12323 asds
as 34567 ds 34 fd 12234 12323 asds
as 345673 ds 34 fd 12234 12323 asds
as 34567 ds 34 fd 12234 12323 asds
as 5343 ds 34 fd 12234 12323 asds
a

asd lkj 234
lklkkl lklk
```

Code:

```
with open('fin', 'r') as f, open('fout', 'w') as f2:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    lines = [a.split() for a in lines]
    reqlines = [a[1]  if a[1].isdigit and len(a[1])==5 else '' for a in lines if len(a) >=2 ]
    for l in reqlines:
        f2.write(l+'\n')
```

Output file: `fout`

```
34567

34567

34567
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are concise but a bit challenging to get started with.  Here is one which says "take the last match if there is at least one five-digit number".

```
for row in zipfile:
    value=re.search(r'(?:.*\D)?(\d{5})(?:\D.*)?$', str(row))
    if value:
        reader.append(value.group(1))
```

You'll notice the change from `findall` to `search` since we only care about match or no match, and the `.*` to skip as much as possible before the match (effectively searching to the end of the string, then backtracking until we find a match) and the decorations around the number to avoid picking a substring out of a number which is longer than 5 digits; and finally the condition to not append anything if there is no match.

Comment: You should probably just write to the output file when you find matches in the input file in a single loop, but I'm not addressing that refactoring in this answer.